# Failed to read module

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I am working on a GWT 2.4/Maven/Spring project that uses a JAR from another project.  I have added a GWT module file (.gwt.xml) to the referenced JAR to make its classes translatable by GWT.  Things worked fine for a while, then all of a sudden (i.e. after one of the many code changes) I am now getting this error in Eclipse:

```
Failed to read module XML file 
   sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@68e72c 
       (org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:compile:default:prepare-package)
           pom.xml     /PivotReportsWeb       line 118 Maven Build Problem
```

PivotReportsWeb is the name of my GWT application. The error refers to *execution* inside the *gwt-maven-plugin* declaration in my pom.xml.  However, Maven happily builds the project from command line with no errors or warnings whatsoever.

Forcing Maven to update project dependencies didn't work, nor did any of the many other tricks I've tried.

Any thoughts, anybody?

---

**UPDATE**

As it turned out, it was a Windows permissions issue! I noticed that I could no longer delete the referenced project's target folder or modify my user permissions on it (even though I am a local admin). So I rebooted and -- VOILA!  Everything works again.

Reminds me of a geeky slogan I saw once on a friend's T-shirt: REBOOT IS SEXY

Comment: I'd say you should inspect the history of the code changes to see if you can find anything relevant to the problem, like library version changes, illegal code added to a GWT module, and so on. You can also try to use maven with higher verbosity, to try to find more clues.

Comment: when exactly does this error happens ?

Comment: Jean-Michel: this error appears in the Eclipse Problems tab right after the project automatically builds.

Comment: Gilberto: I've tried going a few check-ins back but am still seeing this error. I'll try to roll back even further today.